# Simple OpenGL engine

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm thinking about using OpenGL for part of my app, speciffically tile based London tube map. What is the most minimalistic and simplest OpenGL framework that I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, you might find [GLSurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html) handy for your app. Simplest possible OpenGL ES application with the source code is included.

Answer (score 1):

You can use opengl pure. But I recommend using GLUT.

Comment: GLUT is outdated now, isn't it?

Comment: No, its not outdated, its just minimalistic. It's also very portable.